# Jetpack compose how to make buttons after LazyColumn

Tags: android, list, lazycolumn

This code makes buttons always after list rows.
but how to make such implementation:

1. then small list, button on the bottom of the screen,
2. but then list large and larger then screen size, button on the and of the list

```
LazyColumn(
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 20.dp, start = 10.dp)
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            items(list) { price ->
                Item(
                    account = account,
                    selected = viewModel
                ) { onClose() }
            }
                item {
                    BottomButtons(onClose = onClose)
                }
        }
```

I tried and with if statement show button after items and after lazycolumn:

```
        val showButtons by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.toMutableList().size < list.size
            }
        }
```

but buttons flickering

Answer (score 1):

If you want to organize a LazyColumn and a button at the bottom of the screen, you can use this kind of structure (it's not the only solution )

```
Column() {
  Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.9f)) {
    LazyColumn(
      state = state,
      modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 20.dp, start = 10.dp)
            .weight(1f)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        items(list) { price ->
            Item(
                account = account,
                selected = viewModel
            ) { onClose() }
        }
    }
  }
  Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1f)) {
    BottomButtons(onClose = onClose)
  } 
}
```

With this code, you keep the proportion with the weight, and both composable elements are always visible no matter the number of items you have in your LazyColumn.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: not showing BottomButtons at all